# C++ - How to Make Static Dictionary to Lookup Matrix

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix

I am trying to write a C++ class that allows me to access certain matrix elements by a string lookup.  I wanted to create a 'static' class that can do this, such as:

```
#include <unordered_map>
namespace Mine {
static double AA[3][4] = {
    {5.04964676394959,-0.693207030363152,0.0422140829479668,-0.000968959310672217},
    {2.6044054979329,0.288475262243944,-0.0208805589126506,0.000380899394040856},
    {-4.32707864788065,1.07090008760872,-0.0777874445746693,0.00165150952598117}
};
static unordered_map<std::string, double[3][4]> Mine::parameter_store = { {"AA", AA}};
```

With the idea being that I would have several matrices, and could look them up based on a key.  However, this seems to totally and utterly fail with the following error:

```
error: object expression of non-scalar type 'double [3][4]' cannot be used in a pseudo-destructor expression
```

Is it possible to build a lookup table this way in C++?

Comment: Are all the matrices of the same dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

namespace Mine{

template<class T>
using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

Matrix<double> AA = {
    {5.04964676394959,-0.693207030363152,0.0422140829479668,-0.000968959310672217},
    {2.6044054979329,0.288475262243944,-0.0208805589126506,0.000380899394040856},
    {-4.32707864788065,1.07090008760872,-0.0777874445746693,0.00165150952598117}
};

static std::unordered_map<std::string, Matrix<double>* > parameter_store = { {"AA", &AA}};
}


#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << (*Mine::parameter_store["AA"])[0][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*Mine::parameter_store["AA"])[0][1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*Mine::parameter_store["AA"])[1][2] << std::endl;
}
```

output

```
5.04965
-0.693207
-0.0208806
```

The `Matrix<>` template used here causes each row to store its length even though that's redundant. You can avoid this by used a `std::array` (but then you're locked into each matrix having equal dimensions since that's part of the type information) or using some library like Boost that provides a multidimensional array. That's an extremely small inefficiency though and unless you know you need to it might be best to not worry about that.

Comment: Thank you!  And a note for any others that this needs -std=c++11

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping  double[3][4] in a structure/class

```
structure myMatrix {
double arr[3][4];
//if you want to initialize it 
myMatrix(double[3][4] p){
   //copy matrix here
}
};
```

Comment: could I still initialize it as before?